# Scala refined types and type class derivation (Shapeless)

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless

I am learning about [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) type class derivation. One common exercises is to generate a random instance of a given case class. Simply put, the idea is to have something like the following:

```scala
trait Random[C] {
  def gen: C
}

// primitives' instances
implicit val rs: Random[String] = ...
implicit val rd: Random[Boolean] = ...
implicit val rb: Random[Boolean] = ...

// HList and HNil instances
implicit val rhlist: Random[H :: T] = ...
implicit val rhnil: Random[HNil]
```

With an implicit `shapeless.Generic[C]`, we can have then a random instance of `C`. This works well, however I want my generator to respect some rules. For example, `Random[Double]` should also generate not only a random double, but one that respects some bounds. The bound can be provided using an annotation on that field (`case class Foo(@GreaterThan(0) x: Double)`) or using [refined types](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) (`case class Foo(x: Double Refined Positive)`).

I am aware that the [refined types](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) approach might be totally different than annotations. I would like to explore both approaches, or the more idiomatic one. Do you have any hints ? Thanks

Comment: For shapeless derivation, I believe refined types may work better. However, personally, I would rather use a combinator approach.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Any idea how to use refined types ? I am still a beginner .. Should I define `Random` instances for each refined type ?

Comment: No, you provide a way to derive a `Random[T Refined R]` for any type `T` and refinement `R` as long as there is a `Random[T]` and you have some way to filer or tune the generation given the predicate of `R` - something like `implicit def refinedInstance[T, R](implicit underlying: Random[T], predicate: RefinedPredicate[R]): Random[T Refined R]`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am not sure I get the `predicate` part. Do you mind going through a simple example ? thank you

Comment: This is the skeleton of what you want: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/X5BebX15S6KG6VaWNHM9Ow/2 just fill in the implementations of both randoms. The `refined` allows you to refine a raw value _(e.g. a `Double`)_ into a refined one _(e.g. a `Double Refined Positive`)_, which will return an `Option` in case the value doesn't satisfy the predicate, I guess in your case you want to just retry the operation until it works or maybe tune the generation but that one is harder.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Works thanks!! However I am not sure how to handle, for example generating doubles between bounds. I can always retry until I hit the correct number, but this is sorts of a `while` loop that might not be the best idea ..

Comment: You have three options.One is to have a more specific case for cases like `Between` and `GreaterThan` where you can get the bounds as type parameters. The second is do pattern matching on the refined type to derive the randomness predicate. Finally, you could just use a combinators approach and write a little bit of code rather than wanting for magic to happen